# extract rows 10 to 20 from 100 rows in pig

Tags: apache-pig

Please help with this scenario.
Let's say v have 100 rows of a dataset.

How to extract rows 10 to 20 from a total of 100 rows in a dataset using pig.
Thanks
Sai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
W = rank V;
X = filter W by (f1>10) and (f1<=20);
```

Answer (score 0):

same as the above solution but it will not append rank in the output

```
PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' as line;  
B = RANK A;  
C = FILTER B by (rank_A>=10 and rank_A<=20);  
D = FOREACH C GENERATE line;  
dump D;
```